# nlohmann::json usage with better_enum

Tags: c++, json, enums, nlohmann-json

Is it possible to use better enum(https://github.com/aantron/better-enums) with nlohmann::json(https://github.com/nlohmann/json)?

I'm trying to migrate a integer/short field to a better_enum generated class. i did try to add to_json and from_json methods still i'm receiving at compile time.

> error: static_assert failed due to requirement
> 'std::is_default_constructiblestudents::GRADE::value' "types must be
> DefaultConstructible when used with get()"

Here is my code sample i tried to use

> Student.hpp

```
    namespace students {
    BETTER_ENUM(GRADE, short,
                GRADE_1,
                GRADE_2)

    struct Student {
        std::string name;
        GRADE grade;
    };

    inline nlohmann::json get_untyped(const nlohmann::json &j, const char *property) {
        if (j.find(property) != j.end()) {
            return j.at(property).get<nlohmann::json>();
        }
        return {};
    }

    inline nlohmann::json get_untyped(const nlohmann::json &j, const std::string &property) {
        return get_untyped(j, property.data());
    }

    void from_json(const nlohmann::json &j, students::GRADE &x);

    void to_json(nlohmann::json &j, const students::GRADE &x);

    void from_json(const nlohmann::json &j, students::Student &x);

    void to_json(nlohmann::json &j, const students::Student &x);

    inline void students::from_json(const nlohmann::json &j, GRADE &x) {
        x = GRADE::_from_integral(j.at("grade").get<short>());
    }

    inline void students::to_json(nlohmann::json &j, const GRADE &x) {
        j["grade"] = x._to_integral();
    }

    inline void from_json(const nlohmann::json &j, students::Student &x) {
        x.name = j.at("name").get<std::string>();
        x.grade = j.at("grade").get<GRADE>();
    }

    inline void to_json(nlohmann::json &j, const students::Student &x) {
        j = nlohmann::json::object();
        j["name"] = x.name;
        j["grade"] = x.grade;
    }
}
```

file storage code:

```
students::Student student1 = {"vs", students::GRADE::GRADE_1};
nlohmann::json jsonObject = student1;
std::ofstream studentFile("/Users/vs/Projects/test/data/students.json");
studentFile << std::setw(4) << jsonObject << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. From nlohmann::json's [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#how-can-i-use-get-for-non-default-constructiblenon-copyable-types):

> **How can I use get() for non-default constructible/non-copyable types?**
>
> There is a way, if your type is MoveConstructible. You will need to specialize the adl_serializer as well, but with a special from_json overload.

In this case, you'd probably want something like:

```cpp
namespace nlohmann {
    template<>
    struct adl_serializer<students::GRADE> {
        static students::GRADE from_json(const json &j) {
            return students::GRADE::_from_integral(j.get<int>());
        }

        static void to_json(json &j, students::GRADE t) {
            j = t._to_integral();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks unddoch, i even tried similar impl previously but still i see an error as follows

 error: chosen constructor is explicit in copy-initialization
            return {j.get<short>()};

Comment: Maybe try `return GRADE{k.get<short>()};` instead?

Comment: no luck  

error: calling a private constructor of class 'students::GRADE'
            return students::GRADE{j.get<short>()};

Comment: this worked : 

return students::GRADE::_from_integral(j.get<short>());

thanks for help  unddoch